# How to prevent Dialog opening twice in angular material using angular5

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-material

```
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
 <mat-option *ngFor="let person of filteredPersons | async" [value]="person.name" (onSelectionChange)="selectedPersonsInDialog(person)"> <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden src="{{person.imgUrl}}" width="30" height="30" /> <span>{{ person.name }}</span> | <small>ID: {{person.id}}</small> </mat-option> </mat-autocomplete>
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let person of filteredPersons |  async" [value]="person.name"(onSelectionChange)="selectedPersonsInDialog(person)">
          {{person}}  
          </mat-option>  
        </mat-autocomplete>
```

> This is my method in the component class:- Actually
>   selectedPersonsInDialog function is being called twice so, always it
>   displays 2 times dialog with latest selected and one previous selected
>   value.

```
I want to display a dialog only once with latest value selected.

selectedPersonsInDialog(person){
 this.selectedPerson=person;
alert(this.selectedPerson); 
 let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddListOfPersonDialog, {
      width: '500px',
      data: { person:this.selectedPerson}
    });
  }*
```

Comment: can you create a working plunker or stackblitz?

Comment: HTML:- <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let person of filteredPersons |  async" [value]="person.name" 
      (onSelectionChange)="selectedPersonsInDialog(person)">
        <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden src="{{person.imgUrl}}" width="30" height="30" />
        <span>{{ person.name }}</span> |
        <small>ID: {{person.id}}</small>  
      </mat-option>  

    </mat-autocomplete>

Comment: please add the same to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when selection change event pass in every option, so got more then one  event. but you got `$event.source.selected` is `true` in one event which is you selected. so you can manage it.

your html should be like

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let person of filteredPersons | async" [value]="person.name"
                            (onSelectionChange)="selectedPersonsInDialog($event.source.selected,person)">
                    <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden  src="{{person.imgUrl}}" width="30" height="30"/>
                    <span>{{ person.name }}</span>
                    <small>ID: {{person.id}}</small>
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let person of filteredPersons |  async" [value]="person.name"
                        (onSelectionChange)="selectedPersonsInDialog($event.source.selected,person)">
                {{person}}
             </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
```

your component function should be like

```
selectedPersonsInDialog(isSelected: boolean,person){
if(isSelected){
   this.selectedPerson=person;
   alert(this.selectedPerson); 
   let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddListOfPersonDialog, {
      width: '500px',
      data: { person:this.selectedPerson}
    });
  }
}
```